# Как разрешить в инпут ввод только цифр и подставлять пробел после каждых 4-ех символов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можете подсказать, имеется инпут необходимо запретить ввод любых символов кроме цифр и после каждой 4-ой цифры ставить автоматически пробел - "1234 5678 9012 3456". maxlength поставил с учетом пробелов(16 цифр, 3 пробела)

```
<input type="cardnumber" id="clientInputCardnum" maxlength="19">
```

---

Как запрещать ввод символов знаю. Проблема с подстановкой пробела.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда такое не делал, но, может, поможет. Один обработчик — на проверку что вводятся цифры. Другой — на форматирование введенного по шаблону.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#clientInputCardnum');

/** Валидация цифр при вводе*/
input.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode < 48 || evt.keyCode > 57) evt.preventDefault();
});


/** Оформление вывода по шаблону */
input.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
  const pattern = '**** **** **** ****';
  let value = input.value;
  value = getCleanValue(value);
  value = getPatternedValue(value, pattern);
  input.value = value;
});

/** Возвращает очищенную строку (только цифры)*/
function getCleanValue (string) {
  let newString = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if ( +string[i] ) newString += string[i];
  }
  return newString;
}

/** Возвращает оформленную по шаблону строку*/
function getPatternedValue (string, pattern) {
  let newString = '';
  let counter = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    if ( !string[counter] ) continue;
    if (pattern[i] === '*') {
      newString += string[counter];
      counter++;
      continue;
    } 
    newString += pattern[i];
  }
  
  return newString;
}
```

```html
<input type="cardnumber" id="clientInputCardnum">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу уточню, что не разбираюсь в JS, код был взять из ответам **@novvember** и немного изменен.

В основу взято регулярное выражение с негативным просмотром вперед, для установки после каждых 4 цифр символа пробела.

```js
//Скопированная функция
const input = document.querySelector('#InputCardnum1');
input.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
  input.value = input.value
    .replace(/(\d{4})(?!\s|$)/gm, `$1 `)
    .match(/(?:\d{4} ?){0,3}(?:\d{0,4})?/)
});

//Вариант №2, не используем константу
//На сколько я понял принципиальной разницы нет между querySelector
//и getElementById. Хотя querySelector как я понял при нескольких
//одиннаковых id может получить массив данных
document.getElementById('InputCardnum2')
  .addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value
      .replace(/(\d{4})(?!\s|$)/gm, `$1 `)
      .match(/(?:\d{4} ?){0,3}(?:\d{0,4})?/)
})
```

```html
<p><b>Copy:</b><br>
<input type="cardnumber" placeholder="Card Number" id="InputCardnum1">
<br>
<p><b>Способ 2:</b><br>
<input type="cardnumber" placeholder="Card Number" id="InputCardnum2">
```

UPD: убрал проверку ввода в регулярное выражение
Подробнее о рег. выражениях:

```
replace(/(\d{4})(?!\s|$)/gm, `$1 `)
```

Выполняет функцию добавления пробела после каждых 4х идущих подряд цифр
`\d` - диапазон цифр, эквивалентно `[0-9]`
`{4}` - квантификатор, т.е. указано точное количество что 4 цифры идущие подряд
(...) - захватываемая группа, во втором значение `$1` - ее возвращение и пробел
`(?!...)` - негативный просмотр вперед, для того, что бы если группа из 4-х цифр уже разделенная пробелом или является последней не разделялась дополнительно
`...|...` в группе `|` означает логическое или
`\s` - любой пробельный символ
`$` - означает конец строки, нужен специальный параметр `m` - multiline

```
.match(/(?:\d{4} ?){0,3}(?:\d{0,4})?/)
```

Используем для ограничения количества вводимых символов и соблюдения порядка
`(?:...)` - не захватываемая группа, обычно используется для того, что бы установить квантификатор на группу символов в определенном порядке
 `?` - означает 0 или 1 пробел
`{0,3}` - квантификатор группы, т.е. у нас может быть ноль, один, два или три блока разделенных пробелами цифр, не разделенные пробелом будут разделены replace
`(?:\d{0,4})?` - группа, в которой не жесткая привязка количества цифр, служит для того, что бы можно было вводить символы по одному, в ней отсутствует пробел и так как в предыдущей группе используется квантификатор на цифру равный четырем, то при начале ввода каждого из блока номера карты будет срабатывать именно эта часть, до указания четвертой цифры блока.

---

### Предупреждение:

Использование регулярных выражений зачастую снижают скорость выполнения программы, поэтому при обработке больших массивов данных следует постараться избежать сложных конструкций либо регулярных выражений в целом.
Так же повторю, что с данным кодом я экспериментирую ввиду отсутствия необходимого количества знаний, поэтому тестируйте его вдруг решите использовать в проекте.

---

Comment: Знаю, не указал в вопросе этого, но: при вставке ваш код ломается. То есть можно просто  скопировать и вставить "абвгд" и все остается, в то время как у @novvember такого нет. В любом случае, спасибо за возможное решение.

Comment: @rg234 попробовал поправить, проверьте пожалуйста, если не сложно

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо. Не подскажете где можно почитать о регулярных выражениях, знаю только о существовании различных шпаргалках о них.

Comment: До этого с ними сталкивался только пару раз, и то была простая задача.

Comment: @rg234, я изучал их поверхностно, на сайте regex101.com он как онлайн парсер и там список для разных ЯП есть, группы, квантификаторы и проче с примерами. Находится в правом нижнем углу. А так если прям литература нужна, то в теге регулярные выражения много чего есть.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю. Спасибо еще раз за решение, остановился именно на нем.

Comment: @rg234, я думаю справидливо будет оставить верным ответ `@novvember`, так как кроме регулярного выражения, код полностью скопирован от него, спасибо!

Comment: Поменял, оставил @novvember